# Find the probability - Basketball game , free throws

Tags: math, probability

In a basketball game you are given free throws, which of these probability is higher? 
2 shots on 4 attempts OR 3 shots on 6 attempts??

Note: its not exactly 2 out of 4, its at least 2

EDIT:
ok this is wat i feel, please let me know why this approach is wrong. In the first case, there are 2 ways of losing - 0,1 throws out of 4. and 3 ways of winning-2,3,4 (just for calculation;through he would have stopped after getting 2) so the prob of winning is 3/5. same way in the second case the prob of winning is 4/7. comparing these two I get 3/5 > 4/7

Comment: "its not exactly 2 out of 4, its at least 2" -- you obviously haven't seen an NBA center shoot free throws.

Comment: Thanks, that note was for people who have not seen..!

Comment: I don't think that's a very good interview question.

Comment: It depends. If you claim for some analitycal or quantiative position you definetly have to know how to solve such a task - it is one of the simplest task under probability theory.

Comment: I work in the trading industry, and we ask questions like this to see if people have a basic understanding of probability since that's critical to working in the trading/finance industry.

Answer (score 2):

It is Bernoulli trials. Let p be the possibility of a shot. So the probability of 2 out of 4 is C(4, 2)p^2(1-p)^2 + ... + C(4, 4)p^4, where C(n, k) = n!/(k!*(n-k)!). The same with 3 out of 6. You will get two polynomials which you have to compare. Simple math further - which p makes it true or wrong. You will have an equation of six degree, so better plot the graphic and find necessary values of p.

Comment: ok this is wat i feel, please let me know why this approach is wrong. In the first case, there are 2 ways of losing (0,1) throws out of 4. and 3 ways of winning (2,3,4) so the prob of winning is 3/5. same way in the second case the prob of winning is 5/7. comparing these two I get 5/7 > 3/5.

Comment: EDIT:
ok this is wat i feel, please let me know why this approach is wrong. In the first case, there are 2 ways of losing - 0,1 throws out of 4. and 3 ways of winning-2,3,4 (just for calculation;through he would have stopped after getting 2) so the prob of winning is 3/5. same way in the second case the prob of winning is 4/7. comparing these two I get 3/5 > 4/7

Comment: You've committed the logical fallacy of presuming that the cases have equal probability. For example, if p is high (you're a good thrower), P[0]+P[1] could be below 0.001. And if p is low P[0]+P[1] could be more than 0.999

Comment: You fall in a trap of native perception of probability theory. I can inerpret your approach like this: What is the probability of meeting a dinosaur at the street? Two events - "meet" and "not_meet". So we have 50% probability of meeting a dinosaur at the street, which as absurd. Probability theory is all about axioms, elementary and complex events. Please, read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space) to find out what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

**Option 1**

Consecutive throws are independent - Like Deshene said: it is [Bernoulli trials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial).

Your argument is wrong since the probability of losing x throw is not the same as the probability of losing y throws.

**Option 2**

Consecutive throws are dependent - We'll need to build a more profound model.

Still, the probability of losing x throw is not the same as the probability of losing y throws.

---

I believe that in real-life, consecutive throws are dependent (this is only my  belief - it was not empirically proved nor disproved).

Comment: Answering "Do you want me to assume the free throws are independent? Because I don't think they are" is the most correct answer of all.